# How to display TextView in front of more Buttons?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I [have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY5N2.png) 4 Buttons and 1 TextView with dimensions 240x200 and i want this textview to display over all 4 buttons. I tried placing in xml code Text View after buttons and i tried with FrameLayout but it doesn't work in both cases still buttons are over TextView.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.probalayout.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button11"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
        android:background="#906090"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to display that single TextView bigger to cover all 4 buttons or 4 TextViews on top of each Button?

Comment: single TextView bigger to cover all 4 buttons

Comment: increase the textSize and call bringToFront() on textView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Linear Layout and specify the layout direction with the android:orientation attribute.